# Check if the user likes the facebook page or not

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to check if the user liked my page before use my app on it with the following code

```
<body onload="liked()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function liked() {
    FB.api("me/likes/2002200279160150349", function(response) {
        if (response.data.length == 1) {
            alert("page liked already");
        } else {
            alert("page is NOT liked ");
        }
    });
}
</script>

</body>
```

determine that the user is authnticated in another page and logged in properly

Comment: Always alert page is NOT liked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Approach use this method

```
FB.api({
    method:     "pages.isFan",
    page_id:        my_page_id,
},  function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(response){
            alert('You Likey');
        } else {
            alert('You not Likey :(');
        }
    }
);
```

But,This code only works if the user has granted an `extended permission` for that which is not ideal.

[Here's another approach](http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php/).

In a nutshell, if you turn on the "OAuth 2.0 for Canvas" advanced option, Facebook will send a $_REQUEST['signed_request'] along with every page requested within your tab app. If you parse that signed_request you can get some info about the user including if they've liked the page or not.

```
function parsePageSignedRequest() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      return $data;
    }
    return false;
  }
  if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
    if($signed_request->page->liked) {
      echo "This content is for Fans only!";
    } else {
      echo "Please click on the Like button to view this tab!";
    }
  }
```